# quickly run ERROR: run command failed Aborting

Tags: ubuntu-one, python, quickly, pygtk

I have simple PyGTK app made with quickly.

After syncing source files via Ubuntu One and running on other machine I got:

```
$ quickly run 
Can't execute bin/myapp
ERROR: run command failed
Aborting
```

But running directly:

```
$python bin/myapp
```

works.

Any idea? Can it be Ubuntu One messed something? Changin app in Glade (rebuild) didn't fix nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quickly run 
Can't execute bin/myapp
ERROR: run command failed
Aborting

try

chmod +x